# How does extjs Ext.require() works

Tags: extjs

I understand that lets say if we have,

```
Ext.require([
  'Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature',
  'Ext.toolbar.Paging'
]);
```

it will translate those entries into some_path/ux/grid/FilterFeature.js etc

but how does

```
Ext.require([
  'Ext.grid.*',
]);
```

is going to work? it doent know how many js files are below grid/ directory so from client side how can it load them?, is it stuff like lazy loading, i mean if some other file has child js entry it will allow loading?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As part of the build process, we generate a "bootstrap" file which contains information about which files exist. So it doesn't query the filesystem, it just asks the bootstrap for everything under `Ext.grid`.

Comment: suppose if i dont create bootstrap.js file then entries without '*' should be loaded properly? or we always need a bootstrap file?

Comment: No, you need a bootstrap, because you can't interrogate the filesystem remotely using just JS.

Comment: does ordering of entries have any impact? i can see that if a class is extending another parent class two <script> will be added to DOM, but their order is reverse, ie the extended class should come first in dom followed by child.

Answer (score 0):

Only becomes important in a customized production build. By doing this any ExtJS classes you are not using are not included in that build. This helps reduce the foot print of the framework. Unfortunately there is no documentation on how to create this customized build at this point although a beta of the SDK that supposedly does this is available.